# (c) Ncurses function to create Window

Tags: c, ncurses

Beginner Ncurses here. Question, How can I create a function from of making a WINDOW* in Ncurses?

```
WINDOW *mainwindow=newwin(heigh,width,starty,startx);
box(mainwindow,0,0);
```

Unlike a normal variable I am struggling to pass this to a function. What I want to do is simply call a function to create a new Window and pass it back. How does this actually work and what kind of variable is this WINDOW* made of?

```
func createwindow(){
?? temp;
WINDOW *temp=newwin(heigh,width,starty,startx);
box(mainwindow,0,0);
return temp;?
}
```

Comment: When you tried the straight forward approach `WINDOW *createwindow(void){ WINDOW*mainwindow = ... return mainwindow;}`, in how far did you struggle?

Comment: *what kind of variable is this WINDOW\* made of?* basically you should not care. You are not supposed to do anything with that except passing it to ncurses functions. For details you can see [ncurses manpage](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html)

Comment: `WINDOW` is a type, like `FILE`. Do you know how `fopen` works? What would you do if you had to write a function that wraps opening of a file?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the following function main

> WINDOW* border=createwindow(height,width,startpointy,startpointx);

And the function

> 

```
{
   WINDOW* createwindow(int height, int width, int startposy, int startposx)

    WINDOW* temp=newwin(height,width,startposy,startposx);
    box(temp,0,0);
    return temp;
}
```